# Remove space between two words in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following example messages in my database:

```
I dont agree with you
That is something I dont do
This is another string with dont
String without d o n t
```

Whenever a message has the string " dont" in it, I want to remove the space after it so that it becomes one term with the following word:

```
I dontagree with you
That is something I dontdo
This is another string with dont
String without d o n t
```

I have thousands of these kinds of messages in my database. I could query the database in PHP, and then perform a

```
$message = str_replace(' dont ', ' dont', $message)
```

but this would probably take a lot more time then in SQL. Is it possible to make the same operation in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SQL replace() function:

```
update mytable set
mycol = replace(mycol, ' dont ', ' dont')
```

You are right - it would be a *lot* faster in SQL

Comment: Just curious: why would this be so much faster in SQL?

Comment: In general, relational databases allow you to use more memory and processors for handling an operation.  This particular operation can take place on multiple processors.  On the client side, it would typically be serialized.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is **COMPLETELY** irrelevant. The reason is that rowsets are processed in-memory, rather than being piped across the wire and back again. SQL connections are *very* chatty and *that's* why it's faster. Your "multiple processor" reason is rubbish: An app server can have multiple processors and the database only one, but it would still be faster using SQL.

Comment: Oh, I get it now - the OP wanted to actually update the rows in MySQL to reflect these new versions, as opposed to just displaying the rows in his app without the spaces. In that case doing this in SQL would be much faster, yes. I thought you were saying that MySQL's replace function would somehow be faster than PHP's, or something. Thanks. I must've missed your `UPDATE` query when I commented.